# Is "not" correct here? "There's not room in my car's trunk, but yours is bigger"

Tags: grammar, negation

Is it correct to use "not" here, or is it only "no" needed here? If so, which option is more idiomatic?

"There's **not** room in my car's trunk, but yours is bigger".

Comment: Also what about "There isn't room..."? It's just a change in contraction but feels different to me.

Comment: In AmE it is not idiomatic.  It *sounds* British to my ears and would still sound that way even if my neighbor said it.  The real issue with your sentence is that the *but...* clause clashes with with the *There's not...* clause.  *But* must show a contrast between the same thing.  *My trunk is small but yours is big[ger].*  The first clause is about size (small) and so is the second clause.  *There's not room in my trunk but there is plenty in yours.*  The first clause is about *room in the trunk* so is the second.

Comment: @EllieK: I see no significant difference in the relative prevalence of ***There's no room / There isn't room*** in [this AmE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%27s+no+room%2CThere+isn%27t+room&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3)...

Comment: ...and [this BrE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%27s+no+room%2CThere+isn%27t+room&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3). For both corpuses, it looks as if ***There's no room*** has shot up in the last couple of decades, but if we look back to earlier times, ***There isn't room*** was more common both sides of the pond.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm referring to *There's **not** room....*  Both *no* and *isn't* work fine.

Comment: @EllieK OP's contraction ***There's not*** is far less common than ***There isn't*** on both sides of the pond. To repeat - I see no evidence of any kind of US/UK usage split *anywhere* in this area.

Comment: So, if you do not pay attention to the method of contraction, "There is not room in" (without "any") is acceptable? I used to think that "There is no room in..." is only correct (or "There is not any room in...", as PPH said).

Comment: All versions (with or without contractions) are "acceptable". But you also asked *Which is more common?* Despite any confusion caused by Google NGrams treating the contracted ***no*** and ***not*** versions differently, I'd say there's no doubt that the former *(There is **no** room in the inn)* is far more common in general than the latter *(There is **not** room in the inn)*. Note that even in relatively formal contracts, the specific examples here are probably more likely to be contracted than not.

Comment: ...I think it comes down to how the relevant noun (***room***, in this case) is being treated in *syntactic* terms. Consider *There's / There is **no need** to do that!*, which would effectively "require" the inclusion of an indefinite article if phrased as *There is **not a need** to do it* (but the ***not*** version there is very, *very* much less common with *that* example).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

You can say:

*There is **no** room in...

There is **not any** room in...*

Comment: The uncontracted form ***There is not any room in...*** is relatively uncommon, and Google NGrams treats contractions rather oddly, to say the least. But in Google **Books**, the search string [**"There isn't any room in"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22There+isn%27t+any+room+in%22) returns at least *hundreds* of results, compared to just ***five*** different instances of [**"There's not any room in"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22There%27s+not+any+room+in%22). That's an incredibly strong idiomatic preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I went for the uncontracted form for the sake of clarity. As for "there is not any room in" being uncommon, I don't really know. Logically contracted forms should be more common in most cases, but in this particular case, "there is not any room in" brings in over a million search results while for "there isn't any room in", it's under 140 thousand. Interesting point about "there isn't any room in" versus "there's not any room in" though.

Comment: Like I said, NGrams does funny things with contractions, so they're not much use in this context. But Google **Books** simply ignores punctuation marks, so it's a safe bet that almost every match for the search string **"There isn t any room in"** will actually have an apostrophe in ***isn't*** there. And with 10 results per page, if I jump straight to page 10 on my *first* GB link above, it offers shows me the *next* 10 pages (200 results in total). There could be many more pages, but I know even GB starts to get unpredictable / unreliable after a couple of hundred results...

Comment: ...whereas although the uncontracted search string [**"There is not any room in"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22There+is+not+any+room+in%22) initially *appears* to return at least 10 pages of results, if you try to jump to page 10, it only shows up to page 7 anyway (there are just 69 hits in total). Even in *print*, where you'd expect to see more of the uncontracted form, it's obvious which version is preferred.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. What Google Ngrams does to contractions is simple. It coverts all contracted forms to their expanded forms. It's contraction-blind, so to speak. [See this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=isn%27t+any+room+in%2Cis+not+any+room+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20any%20room%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20any%20room%20in%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20any%20room%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20any%20room%20in%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: It replaces ***There isn't any with*** wit ***There is not any***, so you can't split out the contracted instances from the non-contracted ones. But it [rather pointlessly claims](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=There%27s+not+any%2CThere+is+not+any&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThere%20%27s%20not%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CThere%20is%20not%20any%3B%2Cc0) *Replaced **There's not any** with **There 's not any** to match how we processed the books*, so you *can* see matches for just *that* contracted form. I think that's "funny".

Comment: * converts (Sorry for the typo.)